# Ruby script build error with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

[Ruby script build error with Selenium WebDriver]

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::Webdriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "https://www.linkedin.com/"
puts "Linkedin rede de profissionais"
```

Error message:

```
uninitialized constant Selenium::Webdriver (NameError) Did you mean? Selenium::WebDriver
```

Comment: Are you looking for [pt.so]?

Comment: The above script generates the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
teste.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Selenium::Webdriver (NameError)
Did you mean?  Selenium::WebDriver

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include the error message. However, did you try what the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo here, just checked on my IDE, it should be uppercase D:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

see if that helps